# process the document, adding the part of speech

Tags: sed

There is one definition per line, the format is "WORDPartOfSpeech"

The task is to process the document, adding the part of speech
whenever it's defined.  No re-formatting should be done.

For example, if the lexicon is

THE article
BIG adjective
BALL    noun

and the document is

The big red ball fell.

Then the output should be

The/article big/adjective red ball/noun fell.

If I put the lexicon in a database table as 2 fields and I ran an SQL select that outputted as 1 comma separated line in the following format: "The/article,big/adjective,ball/noun" then how would I take that line and process it against the document so that it is outputted like above?

Comment: the line from database lost "red"

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your sql query to preserve any words that don't match a term in your lexicon (perhaps by using an outer join; if you show us that query we could give you more specific advice).  Then, assuming your output then looks something like this (with just a `/` following each term that didn't match your lexicon):

```
The/article big/adjective red/ ball/noun fell/.
```

You could clean it up with `sed` like this (assuming the string had been saved in a variable called `$variablename`:

```
sed 's_\/\([ .]\)_\1_g' <(echo "$variablename")
```

Explanation:

- I used `_` instead of `/` to delimit my `s` command for legibility.  The syntax `s/search/replace/g` is synonymous with `s_search_replace_g`.
- `\/\([ .]\)` tells sed to match anything with a literal `/` (escaped as `\/`) followed by either a space or a period `[ .]`.  anything matching this pattern is stored into a reference because of the `\(` and `\)` surrounding the pattern.
- `\1` in the replacement pattern is the backreference I mentioned earlier.  This works like a variable storing the matched portion we surrounded with parentheses in the search pattern.  In effect, I've told sed to strip out any forward slashes that are followed by a space or a period, without stripping away the space or period itself.

Output:

```
The/article big/adjective red ball/noun fell.
```